# How to extract JSON objects and arrays using python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON for which I am trying to check a particular string matches something in the JSON. I am getting confused as to how I would iterate through it. Once I can iterate through to the right spot I can match it.

Using python. I want to provide a "user" as a variable and then provide the "postname" with another variable and be able to search in this "postname" array for a string that matched my desired string. Can someone help me understand how I would get to this part?
Edit: Adding more details and examples.
"user" - represents the first json object that is user1 or user2 in the JSON example below.
"post" - represents anything inside the "user" object. "post" has a JSON array with strings.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:
from a text I "user1" which is stored in variable user = "user1"
and another info "yesterday_posts" which is stored in post = "yesterday_posts"
Third info I get is "hi you". Now I want to be able to check if "hi you" exists in [user1][yesterday_post].

**JSON EXAMPLE**

```
{
   "user1": {
    "posts": [
     "hello",
     "hello you"
     "Hello awesome"
     ],
    "yesterday_posts": [
     "hi",
     "hi you"
     "Hi awesome"
     ]
   },
    "user2": {
     "post": [
     "awesome",
     "help",
     "works",
     ],
    "postfrom2012": [
     "hi awesome",
     "hi help",
     "hi works",
     ]
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So, you want `if any(search in v for v in myjson[user].values())`?

Comment: Could you clarify which parts of the data correspond to each variable? Give examples and the desired results.

Comment: Maybe something like `if desired_string in myjson[user][postname]:`

Comment: yes, just I though the "postname" would need another for loop as that is inside the "user" object no?

Comment: You don't need a loop, just use it as a dictionary index.

Comment: added more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barmar and Tim Roberts. My question is resolved

Comment: @Barmar what would I do if I only want to check for a partial match in that dict and then return the remaining part from the JSON?

Comment: Use the `any()` function like Tim Roberts showed.

Comment: `any(search in v for v in myjson[user][postname])`